# should i negotiate my salary before the end of my 3 months probation?

Tags: salary, raise, probation

ive been unemployed for a year when i found my current job, they offered me way to little which i negotiated and got a 33% increase to my salary but was still under my two previous jobs.

not wanting to waste the opportunity, i took the job, then i recently found out the job posting of my position on a career website (i didnt see it in the beginning because they approached me).

and the range of salary was specified 1000-2600 , and im only getting after negotiating 1500.

so now im in my 3 months probation period, thinking how i can approach my manager to show him this data, and if its appropriate or not..should i wait for year review or before the end of probation when i can use the job posting as evidence.

there is only one issue im scared of, the salary range in the job posting was in US dollars 400-1000 USD which is impossible to be true since its too low for my postion, so i suspect they didnt change the currency to my local currency which makes it 1000-2600.

what do you guys think?? can i negotiate it more?

Comment: 1500 lies in the 1000-2600 range, so what is the issue here?

Comment: the issue is its in the lower range and i'm over qualified in terms of previous salary and experience

Comment: @Ash Let's see ... 3 months ago, you had to choose between choosing a job with a lower salary or waiting for a job with a higher salary (while extending your unemployment). You weighed the pros and cons of each, and took one option. Now you want to somehow add the pros of the other option to the mix. You are trying to have the cake and eat it too. Things don't work that way in real life, you make a choice and live with it until you get the next opportunity to make a choice. I would be wary of working with someone trying to "game the system" in this fashion.

Answer (score 7):

You should wait until the review period, that is what it is for. Doing it at another time without an overriding reason creates all sorts of issues, particularly with budget and HR and you might be viewed as more trouble than you're worth since you are new and have yet to prove yourself.

Comment: Also you should focus your arguments in your performance during the probation period. Whether you are overqualified or the job posting offers more money has no weight, since you already agreed to the job for your current salary.

Answer (score 3):

The probation period serves to watch for red flags and undesired behavior from either side. If such is discovered, the employment is terminated.

Worst case, asking for more than the agreed upon salary, less than 3 months after the agreement was made, will be seen as undesired behavior and you will be fired for asking. Best case, you ask for the raise, they look at the circumstances, which include you having been unemployed for a year, and you don't get a raise. They already know you won't easily get a higher paying job somewhere else.